# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, typeerror, python-zip

```
for k,v in targets.iteritems():
    price= str(v['stockprice'])

    Bids = str(u''.join(v['OtherBids']))
    Bids = Bids.split(',')

    # create a list of unique bids by ranking
    for a, b in zip(float(price), Bids):
        try:
            del b[next(i for i, e in enumerate(b) if format(e, '.4f')  == a)]
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

I am extracting data from my dictionary but it seems that all of them are in unicode. How may I get rid of the unicode nonsense?

Comment: can you please share the dictionary(target) with its key and values??

Comment: What is your question? Your topic title is **TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration**.  Is your code giving you this error message? Is your question about resolving that error message? Or is your question about getting rid of the Unicode "nonsense"?

Comment: Jim, thanks. I thought unicode was the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I take it your code is giving you the error message, **TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration**.  You are getting this error due to the expression `zip(float(price), Bids)`. This simplified code demonstrates the error:

```
>>> price = str(u'12.3456')
>>> bids = ['1.0', '2.0']
>>> zip(float(price), bids)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

The [Python 2.x `zip()` built-in library function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) requires all its arguments to be iterables. `float(price)` is not an iterable.

If you want to make tuples combining `float(price)` with each element of the array `Bids`, you can use [`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) in the first argument expression.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> price = str(u'12.3456')
>>> bids = ['1.0', '2.0']
>>> zip(itertools.repeat(float(price),len(bids)), bids)
[(12.345599999999999, '1.0'), (12.345599999999999, '2.0')]
```

I don't see that your use of Unicode data types has anything to do with the `TypeError`.